# Django CSS changes are not applied

Tags: html, css, django

I am new to Django and I am using a CSS file for my styles and for now the styles are applied to my html. Now I have created a new class:

```
.post-image {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
  }
```

and have applied the class to the HTML element I want to style like this:

```
<img class="post-image" src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="">
```

But the class `post-image` does not apply somehow. When I change it back to the old class the image gets resized. Also when I tried to edit the old class in my `main.css` the changes were not applied.

My `main.css` file is in my static directory and I have added the static directory in my `settings.py` file like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and I have imported the stylesheet in my `base.html` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'feed/main.css' %}">
```

Comment: Is your 'main.css' loaded correctly?  If your answer is 'yes', clear browser cache, and refresh the page.

Comment: Maybe you are forgetting to use `{% load static %}` in the starting of your `html` file. And make sure you join your static files directory correctly in your `settings.py` file.

Comment: Please provide your setting for static files to make your question clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to clear the cache... :)

Comment: What cache, browser or server-side? Please add a little how-to to improve your answer.

Comment: Yes, I had to empty the cache of my browser which is Google Chrome! On the server side I did not have to clear anything or make any unusual changes.

Answer (score 2):

To erase the browser cache just press Ctrl + shitf + R

Answer (score -1):

You must have the following code in the setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
```